# Share API Data with child Component

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-services

I am pulling data from an api using a service in angular 2 RC1.. it gets pulled into my main component but i would like to also share this data with other components that are children of the main template.. I have made an attempt with inputs but I think I was using them incorrectly so hopefully someone can steer me the right direction on here.. At the moment I am making a call to the api in both the main and the child component

--- Main Component

```
            import {Component} from '@angular/core';
            import {ProjectsMainApi} from "../../../services/projects-main";
            import { RouteConfig, RouteParams, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/router-deprecated';
            import {ProjectMetaInfoComponent} from "./ProjectMetaInfoComponent";


            declare var jQuery: any;

            interface ProjectResult {
                project: Object
            }

            @Component({
                selector: 'projects',
                templateUrl: './app/components/Projects/details/project-single.html',
                directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ProjectMetaInfoComponent]
            })

            export class ProjectDetailsComponent {
                project: Object = {};
                constructor(private _api: ProjectsMainApi, private _params: RouteParams) {

                    this._api.getSinglePortfolio( _params.get("slug") ).then(
                        (res: ProjectResult) => {
                            this.project = res.project[0];
                           console.log(this.project);
                        },
                        (error) => {
                            console.error(error);
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
```

--Child Component

```
            import {Component} from '@angular/core';
            import { RouteConfig, RouteParams, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/router-deprecated';
            import {ProjectsMainApi} from "../../../services/projects-main";
            import { RuntimeCompiler} from '@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler';


            interface ProjectResult {
                project: Object
            }


            @Component({
                selector: 'project-meta',
                template: `
                    <section class="sector intro-pad margin-temp" id="projects-header">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="portfolio-wrap hentry rh-blue-bg white-fg">
                                <div class="breadcrumb">
                                    <ul class="list-reset">
                                        <li>
                                            <div id="main-breadcrumbs" xmlns:v="http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#">
                                                <span typeof="v:Breadcrumb"><a rel="v:url" property="v:title" href="/">Home</a></span> | 
                                                <span typeof="v:Breadcrumb"><a rel="v:url" property="v:title" href="/#/project">Projects</a></span> |   
                                                <span class="current" *ngIf="title">{{ title }}</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="portfolio-introduction-block">
                                    <h1 class="project-header" *ngIf="title">{{ title }}</h1>
                                    <div class="pinfo">
                                        <h2 class="proj-heading rh-blue-lite-fg"><span>Intro...</span></h2>
                                        <p *ngIf="title">{{ title }}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <ul class="list-reset project-meta">
                                        <li class="title rh-blue-lite-fg" *ngIf="headerOne">{{ headerOne }}</li>
                                        <li class="metainfos grey-fg" *ngIf="infoOne">{{ infoOne }}</li>
                                        <li class="title rh-blue-lite-fg" *ngIf="headerTwo">{{ headerTwo }}</li>
                                        <li class="metainfos grey-fg" *ngIf="infoTwo">{{ infoTwo }}</li>
                                        <li class="title rh-blue-lite-fg" *ngIf="headerThree">{{ headerThree }}</li>
                                        <li class="metainfos grey-fg" *ngIf="infoThree">{{ infoThree }}</li>
                                        <li class="title rh-blue-lite-fg" *ngIf="headerFour">{{ headerFour }}</li>
                                        <li class="metainfos grey-fg" *ngIf="infoFour">{{ infoFour }}</li>
                                        <li class="title rh-blue-lite-fg" *ngIf="headerFive">{{ headerFive }}</li>
                                        <li class="metainfos grey-fg" *ngIf="infoFive">{{ infoFive }}</li>
                                        <li class="title rh-blue-lite-fg" *ngIf="headerSix">{{ headerSix }}</li>
                                        <li class="metainfos grey-fg" *ngIf="infoSix">{{ infoSix }}</li>
                                        <li class="metainfos">VISIT</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>  
              `
            })

            export class ProjectMetaInfoComponent {
                title: Object       = {};
                headerOne: Object   = {};
                headerTwo: Object   = {};
                headerThree: Object = {};
                headerFour: Object  = {};
                headerFive: Object  = {};
                headerSix: Object   = {};

                infoOne: Object     = {};
                infoTwo: Object     = {};
                infoThree: Object   = {};
                infoFour: Object    = {};
                infoFive: Object    = {};
                infoSix: Object     = {};

              constructor(private _api: ProjectsMainApi, private _params: RouteParams, private _runtimeCompiler: RuntimeCompiler) {

                    this._runtimeCompiler.clearCache();

                    this._api.getSinglePortfolio(_params.get("slug")).then(
                        (res: ProjectResult) => {
                            this.title       = res.project[0].title;

                            this.headerOne   = res.project[0].meta_header_one;
                            this.headerTwo   = res.project[0].meta_header_two;
                            this.headerThree = res.project[0].meta_header_three;
                            this.headerFour  = res.project[0].meta_header_four;
                            this.headerFive  = res.project[0].meta_header_five;
                            this.headerSix   = res.project[0].meta_header_six;

                            this.infoOne     = res.project[0].meta_info_one;
                            this.infoTwo     = res.project[0].meta_info_two;
                            this.infoThree   = res.project[0].meta_info_three;
                            this.infoFour    = res.project[0].meta_info_four;
                            this.infoFive    = res.project[0].meta_info_five;
                            this.infoSix     = res.project[0].meta_info_six;
                        },
                        (error) => {
                            console.error(error);
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send data from Parent to child using [input](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Input-var.html)

```
<child-component [input]="api_result_variable"></child-component>
```

In the child directive you can use @Input to get the data

Comment: Ive tried that and I get a number of errors one of which is Can't bind to 'input' since it isn't a known native property

Answer (score 0):

If the api service is an Angular 2 service, you can register it with the Angular injector using the provider property. If you register it in the parent, the data is available in the parent and all children. 
See the example here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html